# Session data lost after page redirect

Tags: php, session, redirect

I'm having problems getting simple session data values to persist after a page redirection. A function checks user data sent via Post and if it matches values in a database it sets session data to the values and redirects to another page:

```
  if ($login_ok) {
      //set session data                
      $_SESSION ['online'] = 1;
      $_SESSION ['userid'] = $id;
      $_SESSION ['username'] =  $name;
      //redirect to new page
      redirect('start.php');
}
```

In the new page code the session data is not set. Simple testing returns null values as if the session data wasn't set:

```
  echo 'Session Login Status: ' . $_SESSION ['online'];
  echo 'Session UserID: ' . $_SESSION ['userid'];
  echo 'Session Username: ' . $_SESSION ['username'];
```

Replacing the redirect with the above echo statements works correctly. Is the fact that the session data is set and the redirect activated before any page data has loaded mean that the session variables are not assigned?

To ensure an active session is always available, an include file contains this code:

```
 if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }
```

Any idea what the issue is here?

Many thanks,
Kw

Comment: did you test at start.php to comment your include and write session_start(); without condition?

Comment: @Fran Cerezo The same code is run in start.php via the same include file, ie: if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
  }

Comment: I mean to make a test. Make session_start() without condition, or maybe make an echo session_status(). Perhaps session_status is not returning what you expect. Just for debugging.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. I echoed the session status and it is returning as active. I made a pair of simple pages with links to each other, created a session variable and echoed the results. They both report the variable as unset. Only setting the var in page and echoing returns the data. Thanks for your help, but I'm still baffled by this issue and have checked my files for some code that may be causing this but have found nothing.

Comment: Working on localhost but not on remote server is odd. Is your hosting free or paid? If paid, i would send a ticket to the admins.

Comment: It'a a university server so I expect its been locked down quite tightly. I've had a good look and done some research but the cPanel admin software doesn't seem to offer any way of accessing the php.ini settings file where sessions can be enabled. Annoying. Thanks for your input, all.

Comment: I have a similar problem, my session lost the auth user on header function

Comment: I'm using homestead

Answer (score 1):

Check if the session is set before progress with

```
if isset($_SESSION ['online']) and 
    isset($_SESSION ['userid']) and 
    isset($_SESSION ['username'])
{
    echo 'Session Login Status: ' . $_SESSION ['online'];
    echo 'Session UserID: ' . $_SESSION ['userid'];
    echo 'Session Username: ' . $_SESSION ['username'];
} else {
    echo 'Redirect to login or Session expired';
}
```

Instead of redirect try this

```
$uid = $_SESSION['USERID'];
if (isset($uid) || $uid != NULL) 
{
 if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Location:main.php');
    exit;
    }
    else {
    ?>
    <script>window.location = 'main.php';</script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is evaluating the vars as being set, but after the redirect they are not available.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a server rather than a code issue. Running the code on a localhost server works correctly. Hope this is helpful to people experiencing similar issues.

Saying that, I have no idea how to set the remote server to allow session data. The server has browser based web administration software called cPanel, any suggestions?