# Session support for PHP disabled in cPanel server (image)

Tags: php, session, cpanel

I'm encountering a problem with a server that is seemingly disallowing session support which is causing problems with a site I am building there. Session data can be written but only persists on the same page and is not available elsewhere. I've tested identical code on a localhost server and it works correctly. An output of the session details from phpinfo() follows:

[image]

The server has a browser based admin tool cPanel 64.12 but there doesn't seem to be a way to access the php.ini file so I can enable proper session functionality.

Does the image above indicate that session functionality is indeed disabled, and is there a way to access the php.ini file through cPanel or another approach that can assist? I assume that the security of the server will mean that this in not possible without an admin getting involved which is difficult on an Easter weekend.

Any advice or opinions would be appreciated.

Many thanks,

Kw

Comment: Can you add some test code? And you you being sure to call `session_start()` before using any session variables?

Comment: Yes, I am calling session_start, I have tested the code extensively and it is only the remote server that has the problem.

Comment: I meant could you post the code that you're using to test the problem?

Comment: The issue is discussed in more detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426438/session-data-lost-after-page-redirect?noredirect=1#comment73917499_43426438

Comment: Do you have ssh access to the server?

Comment: @Bogdan Stoica: Yes, I have set up secure https communication to the server for all pages. Do you think this may be related to the session issue?